# Nftables exits with "Killed" when trying to update a set with a huge list of ips

Tags: firewall, nftables

I have a huge list of IPs (about 300 000) I want to put into a nftables set (to use with pbr on openwrt). Currently what I am doing is directly executing add element with all the IPs, but nftables runs for some time then exits saying "Killed". Code for reference:

```
SET={`curl https://reestr.rublacklist.net/api/v3/ips/ | tr -d '" ' | awk '{print substr($0,2,length($0)-2)}'`}
echo add element inet fw4 pbr_wg0_4_dst_ip_user $SET > nft -i
```

I figured a possible solution is to add only some at a time, but that's quite a complicated thing to do and I have no idea how much would it handle.

Is there another way to do this with nftables? Or is this a bad idea overall?

Comment: Trying to pass all this data on the command line (of `echo`, in this case) seems a tremendously bad idea to me.

Comment: What kind of resources (RAM in particular) does your router have? Is it closer to a PC or is it a MIPS-based potato?

Comment: The article [Operations at ruleset level](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Operations_at_ruleset_level) describes bulk operations for nft. Is this relevant to your environment?

Comment: I have previously tried putting the command into a file and running `nft -f ...`
My router has 64 MB of ram (I believe it was half-free), which seems enough, as ips take up 7 MB in plain text and so even less in numbers.